# Three regression models, which one is the best

Tags: regression, logarithm

> In this exercise you will simulate artificial data to compare
>   logarithmic to linear regression models. Start by generating 5.000
>   observations of the error term εt ∼ N(0,1) and 5.000 observations of
>   the variable xt ∼ N(100,1). Hint: use the command rnorm(A,B,C) to
>   generate A observations of a normally distributed variable with mean B
>   and standard deviation C. Have a look at the file bias.r (under topic
>   1) for an example of a simulation exercise.
>
> (a) Given your simulated values of x and ε, generate the variable yt =
>   α +βxt +εt , with α = 1 and β = 3. After simulating the data, run the
>   following three regressions: (i) regress y on x, (ii) regress log(y)
>   on x, and (iii) regress log(y) on log(x). Also make three
>   scatterplots: (i) x against y, (ii) x against log(y), and (iii) log(x)
>   against log(y). Report the estimated coefficients and t-stats of all
>   regressions and show the scatterplots. Which of these three
>   regressions gives the most sensible estimates?
>
> (b) Given your simulated values of x and ε, generate the variable yt =
>   e α x β t e εt , with α = 1 and β = 3. (Hint: use the command exp(a)
>   in R to compute e a ) Run the same three regressions and plots as in
>   question (a). Which of these three regressions gives the most sensible
>   estimates?
>
> (c) Given your simulated values of x and ε, generate the variable yt =
>   e α+βxt+εt , with α = 1 and β = 3. Run the same three regressions and
>   plots as in question (a). Which of these three regressions gives the
>   most sensible estimates?

Could someone give me some clue on how to answer those questions "Which of these three regressions gives the most sensible estimates"? We are using R and I was thinking is it about comparing the t-values of alpha and beta? Like which regression alpha and beta have the highest t-values? Or is there some other argument on which I should base my answer? The scatterplots are somewhat similar in a) in all regressions, and similar in log-regressions in b) and c). I don't need precise answers (since after all, it is about doing an exercise) but if someone could give some clue I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Read the tag description at [tag:self-study] and follow the instructions, including adding the tag to the question. Generally speaking, we encourage homework questions, but (as you expect) hints towards the answer are preferred to full answers. Also, please consider adding more details to what you've tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck. And welcome to the site!

Comment: By the time you have plotted the data **and** their fits, the meaning of "most sensible estimates" should be apparent.

Comment: Hi! Well I tried to plot the data, and for example in the first question, each plot was practically  equally good. So I quess there should be some other way to find out the most sensible estimates.